# How do you uncheck a checkbox when user exits fullscreen in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a checkbox element with the ID "fullscreen." Clicking the checkbox puts the user into fullscreen mode. However, if the user exits the fullscreen mode using f11, the checkbox remains checked.

> I am looking for a script which does as follows:
>
> If the checkbox "fullscreen" is checked, and an "onfullscreenchange"
>   event occurs
>
> Then, uncheck checkbox with the ID "fullscreen."

This is what I have right now:
It does not work--

```js
var el = document.getElementById('fullscreen');
if (el.checked == true){
document.onfullscreenchange = function ( event ) { 
  el.checked = false;
}; 
  }) );
```

How do I do this? Please help!

Comment: hi @SkylixMC, welcome to stackoverflow. just curious, did you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047319/detecting-if-a-browser-is-in-full-screen-mode) yet? also you can detect browser [screen size change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172800/automatically-detect-web-browser-window-width-change) through `window.onresize` or jQuery events. if you can check whether the window is fullscreen or not, then you can uncheck the checkbox right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onfullscreenchange event listener with vendor prefixed to listen to fullscreen change and do whatever required, something like.

```js
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function (event) { 
  var el = document.getElementById('fullscreen');
  if(document.webkitFullscreenElement === null) {
    elem.checked = false
  }
});
```

Alternatively

```
["fullscreenchange", "webkitfullscreenchange", "mozfullscreenchange", "msfullscreenchange"].forEach(
prefixed => document.addEventListener(prefixed, function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('fullscreen');
  el.checked = false;
```

})
);

Comment: That did not work. OK, I have my checkbox as follows:

"<label for="fullscreen" class="fixside">Toggle Fullscreen Mode<input type="checkbox" id="fullscreen" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector leaflet-control-container"><label>"

What script do I need to use if I want to check for if the checkbox is checked, and the user exits fullscreen, uncheck the checkbox? Your script didn't work. It just made it so whenever I click the checkbox to go to fullscreen, it immediately unchecks the checkbox.

Comment: Where would I go from here if I only want to uncheck the checkbox on a fullscreenchange event... if (el.checked == true){

Comment: You can check for  if (document.fullscreenElement).

Comment: For Chrome browser, something like 
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function(event) {
  if (document.webkitFullscreenElement === null) {
    elem.checked = false;
  }
});